# How to add disk space to /var/www for my websites?

Tags: linux, php, centos, web, disk-space-utilization

I did $ df -h and it threw this:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1              9.7G  1.7G  7.6G  18% /
/dev/md2              683G  211M  649G   1% /home
tmpfs                 4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /dev/shm
```

The problem is that my websites are located in /var/www, which I guess belongs to /, and they won't be able to use the disk space for things like images, that need to be placed inside the webroot, eg: /var/www/my_site/public_html/

What can I do about it? Should I move disk space from /home to / ? How?
Or move the sites to /home ?
Any thoughts?

Im using centos 5.5 and apache 2

Comment: If you don't want to do things the hacky way by linking or bind-mounts. Then reinstall the system and either use one big partition, or if really think you want multiple partitions then setup LVM, leaving lots of free space in your VG to be allocated as needed.

Comment: I can't configure much on reinstall, it's a dedicated server that I manage remotely. I can only pick the distro and the architecture, through an automated system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier way will be to move the data to the larger partition, and symlink back into place.

```
 $ mv /var/www /home/
 $ ln -s /home/www /var/www
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remount /home/www in /var/www use bind mounts.

Stop apache:

```
# service apache2 stop
```

Add in fstab line:

```
/var/www /home/www bind defaults,bind 0 0
```

Copy directory:

```
# cp -pR /var/www/ /home/www
```

Mount all:

```
# mount -a
```

Start apache:

```
# service apache2 start
```

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: remount /home/www in /var/www

Comment: I don't get the copy part. Won't I have duplicated files? Should I keep creating sites in /var/www as usual, after doing this? Or in /home/www?

Comment: @HappyDeveloper You can move file "mv /var/www /home/"(don't create copy).

Comment: To be honest I find bind mounts end up confusing things in the long run. They can also result in duplicate data when using a number of backup systems. Hence my suggestion of a simple move and symlink.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like /dev/md2 is quite large, and perhaps should be carved-up using LVM? From the looks of things you have Metadevices setup, which I am guessing is basically your software RAID. you could dedicate md2 to LVM, and split it up into any number of Logical Volumes (LVs). The only difficulty is your /home which you would have to move, temporarily to get /dev/md2 established under LVM. I find that with LVM management of partitions and filesystems becomes a snap. It is always better to use LVM from the get-go, but there is no reason why you could not just migrate to it, partially or completely.